$f(x): f'(x) = 4x^3[f(x)]^2, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(2) = -\dfrac{1}{25}.$ Is it possible to show that $f(x) \neq 0$?

$f(x): f'(x) = 4x^3[f(x)]^2, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(2) = -\dfrac{1}{25}.$ Find $f(1).$

In the solution, they divide both sides by $[f(x)]^2$ to get $\dfrac{f'(x)}{[f(x)]^2} = 4x^3.$ Then both sides are integrated to obtain $- \dfrac{1}{f(x)} = x^4 + C,$ and with $f(2) = -\dfrac{1}{25},$ $C$ is found to be $9,$ and as such $f(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x^4 +9} \implies f(1) = -\dfrac{1}{10}.$
However, I think dividing both sides by $[f(x)]^2$ is only possible when $f(x) \neq 0.$ I actually solved this problem about half a year ago, and for some reason, I was able to convince myself that it is indeed true that $f(x) \neq 0.$ I left a note highlighting the terms "$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$" and "$f(2) = -\dfrac{1}{25}$" and draw implication arrows to $f(x) \neq 0.$ I couldn't figure out what I was thinking back then, but I am now unable to arrive at the same conclusion. Now I could only see that if $f(x) \neq 0,$ then $f(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x^4 +9},$ and if $f(x) = 0,$ then $f'(x) = 0.$ None seems to indicate that $f(1) \neq 0$ to justify the division. I hope to receive some help.
Thank you!

Do you know the existence and uniqueness of ODE?

@BoweiTang I just looked it up and I'm afraid I'm not familiar with this theorem. Please let me know if this theorem is necessary in this case.

Since $y=0$ is a solution, any other solutions do not intersect the line $y=0$(i.e. it is either positive or negative)

@BoweiTang Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure I understand the above statement.

Since $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$ we have $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$, so $$f(1)\leq f(2)<0\implies f(1)\ne 0 $$

$f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$, but in any case this works.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer I somehow saw $x^2$.... edited now, thanks.

Thank you very much!

@nonuser Welcome!


Existence and Uniqueness Theorem For ODE
$R$ is a rectangular region defined by $a\leq x\leq b, c\leq y\leq d$ that contaions $(x_0,y_0)$ in its interior, If $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on $R$, then there exists Interval $I_0=(x_0-h,x_0+h)$ contained in $[a,b]$ and a unique function $y(x)$ which is the solution of $\begin{cases}\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y) \\ y(x_0)=y_0 \end{cases}$.

So, the solution of this initial value ODE is unique.
Another way:(Just for the ODE, no initial value)
The solution curves of the ODE do not cross(also a theorem) and $y=0$ is a solution, so any other solution curves are either positive or negative. If it is positive at $(x_0,y_0)$ and negative at $(x_1,y_1)$, then since the curve is continuous,  there must exist at least a point such that the value is $0$, contradiction.

I struggle to understand this answer, but it's more of a problem on my part as I do not possess the relevant concepts. But thank you very much for your help!

No need of an existence and uniqueness theorem, since your solution is explicit.
Let $I$ be the largest interval around $2$ on which $f$ does not vanish (so, $f$ tends to $0$ at the finite endpoint(s) of $I$, if any). You already proved that
$$\forall x\in I\quad f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^4 +9}.$$
Since $-\frac{1}{x^4 +9}$ only vanishes  at $\pm\infty$, this proves that $I=\Bbb R$.

Would the downvoter mind explaining what doesn't please him/her?

Hi, thank for your answer! I just want to let you know that I'm not the downvoter and I'm also looking to hear further discussion on your answer.
